# No qualifying bean of type 'com.netflix.client.config.IClientConfig' available:expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-ribbon

> I'm creating a loadbalancer using Netflix round ribbon but i am not able to
>   auto wire `IClientConfig` this object.

I tried this also 
`@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages{"com.netflix.client.confg.IClientConfig"})`

but this is also not working for me.

I'm getting this exception

org.spring framework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.netflix.client.config.IClientConfig' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Comment: Have you written @ Service annotation or @ Component annotation on the class IClientConfig.? are you calling this bean while application is starting or at a certain point after application has started?

Comment: yes, i have mentioned @Configuration  annotation this is my code      ``@Configuration
public class ClientAppConfiguration {

 @Bean
 public IRule ribbonRule(IClientConfig config) {
  System.out.println("HERE");
  return new BestAvailableRule();
 }

 @Bean
 public IPing ribbonPing() {
  return new PingUrl();
 }

}``

Comment: Typically this means you have a ribbon bean that has been picked up by the normal application context. These need to be defined in separate configuration classes and referenced by @RibbonClient annotations

Comment: i have that separate class in  that i have mentioned @RibbonClient annotation by mentioned my configuration class name      ``@RibbonClient(name = "loadbalancer-web", configuration = ClientAppConfiguration.class)
``  @spencergibb

Comment: Remove `@Configuration` from that class as documented

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your dependencies are not configured correctly. 
Is `ribbon-core` added as compile dependency in `build.gradle` or `pom.xml`?

please check if you have

```
runtime group: 'com.netflix.ribbon', name: 'ribbon-core', version: '2.7.17'
```

or

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.netflix.ribbon</groupId>
    <artifactId>ribbon-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.17</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```